# What is the correct <object> to use to connect my elasticsearch repository to the INCEpTION NER annotation program

Tags: json, elasticsearch, named-entity-recognition

I have setup a local environment for text annotation and would like to use the INCEpTION application developed here: https://github.com/inception-project/inception/blob/main/CONTRIBUTORS.txt

When trying to connect to my repository I can connect and find documents using their example found here: https://inception-project.github.io/releases/22.1/docs/user-guide.html#sect_external-search-repos

But when trying to connect to my repository created and indexed with FSCrawler I can't get the search to work.

The mapping for the their example is:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "doc": {
          "properties": {
            "text": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "metadata": {
          "properties": {
            "language": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "source": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "timestamp": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "uri": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my index mapping is:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "raw_as_text": {
            "path_match": "meta.raw.*",
            "mapping": {
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              },
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "attachment": {
          "type": "binary"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "properties": {
            "group": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "owner": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "file": {
          "properties": {
            "checksum": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "created": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "extension": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "filename": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "store": true
            },
            "filesize": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "indexed_chars": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "indexing_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "last_accessed": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "last_modified": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "url": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index": false
            }
          }
        },
        "meta": {
          "properties": {
            "altitude": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "author": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "comments": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "contributor": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "coverage": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "created": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "creator_tool": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "format": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "identifier": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "keywords": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "language": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "metadata_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "modifier": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "print_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "publisher": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "rating": {
              "type": "byte"
            },
            "relation": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "rights": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "source": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "path": {
          "properties": {
            "real": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "fields": {
                "fulltext": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "tree": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "fscrawler_path",
                  "fielddata": true
                }
              }
            },
            "root": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "virtual": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "fields": {
                "fulltext": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "tree": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "fscrawler_path",
                  "fielddata": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can search both repositories fine from anywhere else using the standard _search, matching the "content" object

[image: vue standard search]

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en",
    "source": "My favourite document collection",
    "timestamp": "2011/11/11 11:11",
    "uri": "http://the.internet.com/my/document/collection/document1.txt",
    "title": "Cool Document Title"
  },
  "doc": {
      "text": "This is a test Document"
  }
}
```

The same query works on the example even when moving the example 1 level up =

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en",
    "source": "My favourite document collection",
    "timestamp": "2011/11/11 11:11",
    "uri": "http://the.internet.com/my/document/collection/document1.txt",
    "title": "Cool Document Title"
  },
  "doc": "This is a test Document"
  }
}
```

Which object do I need to specify below in order to access the "content" object of my mapping

[image: Inception Search Setup]

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is a functionality issue unfortunately.

mapping has to be very specific in order to use this, remapping (changing fscrawler mapping) does not work unless document mapping is very specific.

Simply changing fields and types does not work.

https://github.com/inception-project/inception/issues/2516